# How to install class bench using make all and bashrc

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, package-management, bashrc

Class bench is program for Linux,Classbench duty is create packets and generate some rules which they call them filter set.In class bench there is three folder:

1. trace_generator
2. db_generator
3. parameter_files

Note: `trace_generator`'s duty is to generate packets, `db_generate`'s duty is create filter set, `paremeter_files` is like library.

Ok ,Know how to install db_gerater and trace_generator? simple! just go to their path and write "make all".Know If you want to run db_generater you should just type this command

`db_generator -bc acl3_seed 10000 2 0.5 -0.1 MyNewFilters10k` but when I write that I saw linux terminal does not support this I search and find I have to add this to my bashrc also I typed !/.bashrc but now I do not know what I should add here.

Before that I installed NS2 which is network simulator I wrote something about NS2 in there but now for classbench I do not know what I should add here?
By the way acl3_seed in the parameter_files

Comment: Isn't there a Ubuntu package for this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret what you're saying, add this to your .bashrc:

```
function make_and_run_db_generator {
    local dir=$1
    shift
    cd "$dir" && make all && ./db_generator "$@"
}
```

Make it visible in your current shell: `. ~/.bashrc`

And then you'd type

```
make_and_run_db_generator /some/dir  -bc acl3_seed 10000 2 0.5 -0.1 MyNewFilters10k
```

Comment: Did you really understand what he's asking?